# css overflow and margin-left

Tags: css, overflow

I have three divs inside a parent div with overflow:hidden; and I want to show the third. So I thought, I could give the first div an margin-left and the two other will be shift to the left.

```
<div style="width:1000px;background:red;overflow:hidden;height:50px;">
    <div style="width:1000px;height:50px;float:left;margin-left:-2000px;">
    1
    </div>
    <div style="width:1000px;height:50px;float:left;">
    2
    </div>
    <div style="width:1000px;height:50px;float:left;">
    3
    </div>
</div>
```

But it shows the second div. But if I add margin-left:-1000px; to the second div and replace margin-left:-2000px; to -1000px on the first div it will work correctly. I don´t understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first div is moved 2000 px left outside the parent element.  This basically "removes" it from the relative positioning of everything else inside the parent.  In other words, the remaining elements are positioned inside the parent as if the first div was never there. Div 2 is positioned relatively as if it was the first element in the parent, i.e. at left:0.    If you want to position div 2 outside the parent, you need to explicitly define its position (like setting its margin:-1000px).

To see whats happening clearer, go to your fiddle and set the 3 child divs to width of 100px, keeping the parent at 1000px. Play with the margins some more.  You should see whats happening.

EDIT: If all you are trying to do is show a specific div and hide the other two, just set the other two to `display:hide`.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the explanation. It lights everything up for me, but that I don´t understand is why the first div is "removed" from the relative positioning, because I have not defined any absolute positioning. If I an element has a margin-left of for example -10px is it always absolute?

Comment: I'm trying to build a carousel and so unfortunately I can´t work with display properties

Comment: it is removed from the RELATIVE positioning.  Nothing to do with absolute...  If you set any property of an element so that it is completely outside the boundaries of its parent, it no longer has any impact on the other elements still inside the bounding areas.  The second div, with no changes to its margin or position properties, will behave as if it is the first element in the parent, because (as far as its concerned) now it is.  That's just the way HTML/CSS works.  Again, I suggest you play with the fiddle, set the widths of the inner elements to 100px, and play with margins.

Comment: Another way, if you position an element outside its container, it can't interact with anything still inside the container.  The only way to affect the position of the elements inside the container is to explicitly set its position.

Answer (score 0):

When you set -1000px to div, this div is no longer in relative position, so the another divs assumes relative position from parent.

Fiddle Example for testing:
http://jsfiddle.net/FvBwC/5/

```
<div class="parent">    
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
</div>

.parent { width:1000px; background:red; overflow:hidden; height:50px;  }
.one, .two, .three { width: 1000px; height: 50px; float: left; }
.one { background: blue; margin-left: -1000px; } 
.two { background: yellow; margin-left: -1000px; }
.three { background: green; }
```

But for better solution I'd go with display: none in CSS or .hide() in jQuery.